# Postgres optimize SELECT and indexes

Tags: postgresql, select, optimization, indexing

I have written a query to summarise financial transactions so that I can go back to any date and find out what the financial position was at that time.

The data is multi company so the data holds information for all the group companies

Being financial information, some of the accounts reset themselves at each year end whilst others have a running balance.

The structure of the tables is:

nominal_account - Return 1 row for each account

nominal-transaction_lines - the full dataset

nominal_period_year - is a summary of transactions that is based on the nominal account, month/year and the financial company.

My SQL below works but takes over a minute to generate (the SQL below is based on today's date).

The query is broken into a few sections.

The first part of the case (na1.id=178) is a special account that is the summary of all income/expenditure records for that financial year.

The second part first looks for any records in the summary table until the last month end and then goes to the transaction table to find any records since the beginning of the current month. Added together that makes the balance.

At present the transaction table has around 25m records and the summary table 26000.

I am not asking for the query to be written for me, just some hints as to how to speed it up. So if anyone could suggest ways to optimize it or which indexes would help to speed it up, I would be very grateful.

```
SELECT id, nominal_code AS nom_code, description AS descr, COALESCE(management_type,0) AS type,
    case 
        when na1.id = 178
        then    (SELECT coalesce( (SELECT sum(period_movement) 
                                FROM nominal_period_year JOIN nominal_account on nominal_account.id = nominal_period_year.nominal_account
                                WHERE   (period_key/10000000000) <= 201704 AND
                                financial_company = 1 AND
                                nominal_account.profit_or_balance = true)
                                +
                                (SELECT sum(period_movement) FROM nominal_period_year WHERE nominal_account = na1.id AND                
                                (period_key/10000000000) <= 201803 AND nominal_period_year.financial_company = 1)
                                +
                                (SELECT GREATEST(0, sum(db_Amount)) - GREATEST(0, sum(cr_Amount))
                                FROM nominal_transaction_lines
                                WHERE transaction_date between '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-27'
                                AND original_id = 0
                                AND reversed_by = 0
                                AND status = 'A'
                                AND financial_company = 1 AND status = 'A' AND nominal_account = na1.id)
                                ,0.00) AS balance)
                    ELSE

                        (SELECT coalesce(
                            (SELECT sum(period_movement) FROM nominal_period_year WHERE nominal_account = na1.id AND
                            (case
                                when na1.profit_or_balance = true 
                                    then (period_key/10000000000) > 201704
                                ELSE period_key > 0
                            end)

                            AND (period_key/10000000000) <= 201803 AND nominal_period_year.financial_company = 1)

                            +

                            (SELECT GREATEST(0, sum(db_Amount)) - GREATEST(0, sum(cr_Amount))
                            FROM nominal_transaction_lines
                            WHERE transaction_date between '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-27'
                            AND original_id = 0
                            AND reversed_by = 0
                            AND financial_company = 1 
                            AND status = 'A' 
                            AND nominal_account = na1.id)
                            ,0) AS balance)
                    end
                    FROM nominal_account AS na1
                        order by nom_code;
```

Comment: Even though you do not show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output so that I have to guess, I'd say that your problem is the many subselects in the `CASE` expression. They have to be executed for each row found in `nominal_account`. Perhaps you can run these aggregations with a `GROUP BY` in a subselect in `FROM` or in a CTE.

Comment: The use of CTEs did the trick. By splitting the selects into 3 separate CTEs and then  doing a FULL JOIN at the end, the query time went from over a minute to less than a second. THANKS